# Querying embedded documents of one given parent document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a mongoid model class "Event" embedding many of class "Participant". Participant has a field "email". Now somewhere in the code I get a reference to one specific Event instance named "@event".

How do I now query the participants of ONLY that instance for an participant with email = XYZ?Not all participants in the collection, just the ones of this given instance @event.

Any ideas?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
@event.participants.where(email: 'XYZ') # this will help you query what ever you want
#or
@event.participants.find_by_email 'XYZ' #this will get exactly one record
```

Comment: You could also use `@events.participants.find_by(email: '...')` if you're just looking for one.